# bootstrap.min.css X in top right corner

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem where bootstrap.min.css creates an X in the top right corner of my [webpage](http://statemodelrnd.camerondevine.me) ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oehlf.png)). By commenting out `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">` in my html file the X is removed, along with much of the other formatting. How can this X be removed while still keeping the rest of bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: Those come from the `i` elements with the classes `form-control-feedback`/ `glyphicon` inside the form you have in section `#page5`. Now you could remove those elements from the HTML - but seeing the `form-control-feedback` class, they probably provide some sort of functionality within the form - in that case, I'd rather investigate why they are positioned fixed, instead of in relation to the form somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe suggested the i elements were the issue. Because they were not needed for anything else on the site it was safe to remove them.